# Combination of function with equal definite integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Consider continuous functions $f,g:(0,1)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ such that $$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1g(x)dx$$
and there is a subinterval $(a,b)\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Define the following integral for integers $n\ge0$.
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{[f(x)]^{n+1}}{[g(x)]^n}dx$$

Which of the following is true?

1. $I_1>I_0$
2. $I_1<I_0$
3. $I_1=I_0$
4. None of the above

My attempt

I substituted $g(x)=1$ and $f(x)=2x$ and got check the value of integral and got option 1. I want to know how to do this properly. Hints please.

Comment: Oh, you did a meta assumption that there exists unique answer to this question, and find that by looking to a single case. Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\eqalign{I_1 - I_0 &= \int_0^1 \left( \frac{f(x)^2}{g(x)} - f(x) \right)\; dx
- \int_0^1 (f(x) - g(x))\; dx\cr
&= \int_0^1 \frac{(f(x) - g(x))^2}{g(x)} \; dx}$$

Comment: So if we have $g(x)<0$ on $(0,1)$ then this integral will be negative and if we have $g(x)>0$ then this integral will be positive. So (4) should be the option.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer as it was wrong.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Except that $g:(0,1) \to (0,\infty)$ was assumed, so you can't have $g(x) < 0$.

Comment: So it is always greater than zero is it. I just want to make sure. Because that would mean my guess was correct.